# tmux and vim are frozen

Tags: vim, tmux

I just started using `tmux`. Running a session with `vim`. Tried to exchange split buffers in `vim`. Usually I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>. Don't use this combination very often so don't have it mapped to anything else. For some reason my `vim` session froze. Not sure what happened. I can execute `tmux` commands and switch between sessions but cannot do anything with `vim`. My guess is that a keyboard combination mentioned above does something with the session (locks it maybe). Google search didn't reveal any useful results. Does anyone know what I have done with my session and how to unlock it?

Here is my `.tmux.conf`

```
# Smart pane switching with awareness of Vim splits.
# See: https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator
is_vim="ps -o state= -o comm= -t '#{pane_tty}' \
    | grep -iqE '^[^TXZ ]+ +(\\S+\\/)?g?(view|n?vim?x?)(diff)?$'"
bind-key -n C-h if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys C-h"  "select-pane -L"
bind-key -n C-j if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys C-j"  "select-pane -D"
bind-key -n C-k if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys C-k"  "select-pane -U"
bind-key -n C-l if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys C-l"  "select-pane -R"
bind-key -n C-\ if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys C-\\" "select-pane -l"
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-h select-pane -L
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-j select-pane -D
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-k select-pane -U
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-l select-pane -R
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-\ select-pane -l
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
bind | split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind - split-window -v -c "#{pane_current_path}"
source-file .lightline.tmux

# List of plugins
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible'

# Other examples:
# set -g @plugin 'github_username/plugin_name'
# set -g @plugin 'git@github.com/user/plugin'
# set -g @plugin 'git@bitbucket.com/user/plugin'

# Initialize TMUX plugin manager (keep this line at the very bottom of tmux.conf)
run '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'
```

Comment: have you pressed `CTRL+S`? try pressing `CTRL+Q`

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo that's exactly what happened. `Ctrl+Q` worked.

Comment: This is actually your terminal doing it, not vim. Have a look here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12146 for the reason behind that

Answer (score 25, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> will freeze a terminal session, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> when it happens. I've remapped my buttons for split jumping to be <kbd>SPACE</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>/<kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd>/<kbd>l</kbd> because its easier and less likely to hit that annoying freeze command.

Comment: that's exactly what happened. `Ctrl+Q` worked. What is the purpose of freezeing a session?

Comment: Something to do with the way old terminals had to send the keycodes across and they needed a way to have an on-off switch to pause and resume sending. I'm not very familiar with its correct use but I did find out about it because I also froze my session.

https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/7263/history-of-ctrl-s-and-ctrl-q-for-flow-control

Answer (score 11):

If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> fails and the window is still frozen,
`<prefix>`+<kbd>:</kbd> and then inputting `respawn-pane -k` worked for me.

Comment: This will kill the tmux pane(l) and will create a new one in it's place. It will unblock my flow, but it will kill the vim session as well. I mean that it will not unfreeze vim ... :(